# Cocos 2D - Changing a Game Characters state from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, cocos2d-iphone

I am learning Cocos2D from the Ray Wenderlich book in my spare time but also making changes to it if it does not explain how to do something that I could see myself needing in the future. I am currently stuck because of my very limited knowledge.

I wish to use the GamePlayLayer Class to randomly change the character state of the TBT class.

I have checked each State and they all work (checked by making them the spawn state) so the problem is most likely in the gamePlayLayer.m file where I have attempted to make my own method.

I seem to be able to get it to change its state to kStateThrowing but it changes straight back (in 0.3 of a second!) to kStateIdle before the animation plays and has the following output...

`2013-11-21 13:45:07.938 Spaceviking[981:12c03] CHANGING STATE TBT!!!!!!`

`2013-11-21 13:45:07.939 Spaceviking[981:12c03] TBT->Changing State to throwing`

`2013-11-21 13:45:07.967 Spaceviking[981:12c03] TBT Going to Idle`

`2013-11-21 13:45:07.970 Spaceviking[981:12c03] TBT->changing state to idle`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Code listed below...

```
//  CommonProtocols.h

#ifndef SpaceViking_CommonProtocols_h
#define SpaceViking_CommonProtocols_h

typedef enum {
    kDirectionLeft,
    kDirectionRight
}
PhaserDirection;

typedef enum {
    kStatespawning,
    kStateIdle,
    kStateWalking,
    kStateIdleTilt,
    kStatebackTilting,
    kStateforwardTilting,
    kStateAttacking,
    kStateTakingDamage,
    kStateThrowing,
    kStateLosingALife,
    kStateDead,
    kStateTravelling,
    kStateRotating,
    kStatetest

}
CharacterStates; //1

typedef enum {
    kObjectTypeNone,
    kPowerUpTypeHealth,
    kPowerTypeMallet,
    kEnemyType1BT,
    kEnemyType2BT,
    kEnemyType3BT,
    kEnemyTypePhaser,
    kVikingType,

} GameObjectType;


@protocol GamePlayLayerDelegate

-(void)createObjectOfType:(GameObjectType)objectType
withHealth:(int)initialHealth
atLocation:(CGPoint)spawnLocation
               withZValue:(int)ZValue;

-(void)createPhaserWithDirection: (PhaserDirection)phaserDirection
                     andPosition:(CGPoint)spawnPosition;


#endif
```

---

```
//  GamePlayLayer.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "CCLayer.h"
#import "SneakyJoystick.h"
#import "SneakyButton.h"
#import "SneakyButtonSkinnedBase.h"
#import "SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "CommonProtocols.h"
#import "TBT.h"

@interface GamePlayLayer : CCLayer <GamePlayLayerDelegate> {
    CCSprite *vikingSprite;
    SneakyJoystick *leftJoystick;
    SneakyButton *jumpButton;
    SneakyButton *attackButton;
    CCSpriteBatchNode *sceneSpriteBatchNode;
}
@end

------------------------------------------------

//  GamePlayLayer.m
#import "GamePlayLayer.h"

@implementation GamePlayLayer
-(void) dealloc {
    [leftJoystick release];
    [jumpButton release];
    [attackButton release];
    [super dealloc];
    }

    --DELETED BELOW 2 METHODS AS NOT NEEDED FOR THIS QUESTION--
-(void)initJoystickAndButtons {
    }
-(void)applyJoystick:(SneakyJoystick *)aJoystick toNode: (CCNode *)tempNode forTimeDelta:(float)deltaTime
{  
    }

-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime {
    CCArray *listOfGameObjects =
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode children];                     
    for (GameCharacter *tempChar in listOfGameObjects) {         
        [tempChar updateStateWithDeltaTime:deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:listOfGameObjects];                         
    }
}
-(void) createObjectOfType: (GameObjectType)objectType
                withHealth:(int)initialHealth atLocation:(CGPoint)spawnLocation withZValue:(int)ZValue {
    if (objectType == kEnemyType1BT) {
        CCLOG(@"creating 1BT");
        TBT *tBT = [[TBT alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"BT_anim_1.png"];
        [tBT setCharacterHealth:initialHealth];
        [tBT setPosition:spawnLocation];
        [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:tBT
                                     z:ZValue
                                   tag:k1BTTagValue];
        [tBT release]; 
    }
}

--BELOW IS THE METHOD I HAVE CREATED TO CHANGE THE STATE--

-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState {
    [self stopAllActions];

    int x =  (arc4random() % 3);

    TBT *tBT = [[TBT alloc]
                  initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache
                                        sharedSpriteFrameCache]
                                       spriteFrameByName:@"BT_anim_1.png"]];
    if (x>0) {
        CCLOG(@"CHANGING STATE TBT!!!!!!");

        [tBT changeState:kStateThrowing];

        [tBT setDelegate:self];
        [tBT release];    
    }   
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self !=nil) {
        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector]. winSize;
        self.TouchEnabled = YES;
        srandom(time(NULL)); 

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
             addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"scene1atlas.plist"];          // 1
            sceneSpriteBatchNode =
            [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scene1atlas.png"]; // 2
        } else {
            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
             addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"scene1atlasiPhone.plist"];          // 1
            sceneSpriteBatchNode =
            [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scene1atlasiPhone.png"];
        }
        [self addChild:sceneSpriteBatchNode z:0];                
        [self initJoystickAndButtons];                           
        BC *viking = [[BC alloc]
                          initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache
                                                sharedSpriteFrameCache]
                                               spriteFrameByName:@"BCmoving_anim_1.png"]];            
        [viking setJumpButton:jumpButton];
        [viking setAttackButton:attackButton];
        [viking setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width * 0.19f,
                                screenSize.height * 0.19f)];
        [viking setCharacterHealth:3];

        [sceneSpriteBatchNode
         addChild:viking
         z:kVikingSpriteZValue
         tag:kVikingSpriteTagValue];          



        [self createObjectOfType:kEnemyType1BT withHealth:3 atLocation:ccp(screenSize.width * 0.0439f, screenSize.height * 0.822f) withZValue:10];

       ---THE BELOW SELECTOR IS WHAT I HAVE USED TO DO A TIMED STATE CHANGE (METHOD ABOVE)--

       [self schedule:@selector(changeState:) interval:1.0f];

        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;   
}
@end
```

---

```
//  TBT.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GameCharacter.h"

@interface TBT : GameCharacter {   
    //This is for the required animations
    CCAnimation *tiltingAnim;
    CCAnimation *transmittingAnim;
    CCAnimation *loseLifeAnim;
    CCAnimation *throwingAnim;
    CCAnimation *afterThrowingAnim;    
    CCAnimation *shootPhaserAnim;    

    GameCharacter *vikingCharacter;
    id <GamePlayLayerDelegate> delegate;

}
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <GamePlayLayerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *tiltingAnim;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *transmittingAnim;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *loseLifeAnim;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAnimation *throwingAnim;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCAnimation *afterThrowingAnim;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCAnimation *shootPhaserAnim;

-(void)initAnimations;
-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState;
@end


//  TBT.m
#import "TBT.h"

@implementation TBT

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize tiltingAnim;
@synthesize transmittingAnim;
@synthesize loseLifeAnim;
@synthesize throwingAnim;
@synthesize afterThrowingAnim;
@synthesize shootPhaserAnim;

-(void) dealloc {
    delegate = nil;

    [tiltingAnim release];
    [transmittingAnim release];
    [loseLifeAnim release];
    [throwingAnim release];
    [afterThrowingAnim release];
    [shootPhaserAnim release];

    [super dealloc];
}
--BELOW METHOD NOT NEEDED FOR THIS QUESTION
-(void)shootPhaser {}

-(CGRect)TBTboundingBox {
    CGRect tbtBoundingBox = [self boundingBox];
    float xOffset;
    float xCropAmount = tbtBoundingBox.size.width * 0.5482f;
    float yCropAmount = tbtBoundingBox.size.height * 0.1f;

    tbtBoundingBox =
    CGRectMake(tbtBoundingBox.origin.x + xOffset,
               tbtBoundingBox.origin.y,
               tbtBoundingBox.size.width - xCropAmount,
               tbtBoundingBox.size.height - yCropAmount);

    return tbtBoundingBox;

}

-(void)changeState:(CharacterStates)newState {
    [self stopAllActions];
    id action = nil;

    [self setCharacterState:newState];

    switch (newState) {
        case kStatespawning:
            CCLOG(@"TBT->Changing State to Spwaning");
            [self setDisplayFrame:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
              spriteFrameByName:@"BT_anim_1.png"]];
            break;


        case kStateIdle:
            CCLOG(@"TBT->schaning state to idle");
            [self setDisplayFrame:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
              spriteFrameByName:@"BT_anim_1.png"]];

            break;

        case kStateThrowing:
            CCLOG(@"TBT->Changing State to throwing");
            action = [CCSequence actions:
                      [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:throwingAnim
                                restoreOriginalFrame:NO],
                      [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0f],
                      //[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:shootPhaserAnim
                      //          restoreOriginalFrame:NO],
                      [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self
                                          selector:@selector(shootPhaser)],
                      [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:afterThrowingAnim
                                restoreOriginalFrame:NO],
                      [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.1f],
                      nil];

            break;

        case kStateLosingALife:
            CCLOG(@"TBT->Losing a life");

            break;

            case kStateDead:
            CCLOG(@"TBT->changing state to dead");
            action = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:loseLifeAnim];

            break;

        default:
            CCLOG(@"unhandled state %d in TBT", newState);
            break;
    }
    if (action !=nil) {
        [self runAction:action];
        }
}

-(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime: (ccTime)deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:(CCArray*)listOfGameObjects {
    if (characterState == kStateDead)
        return;
    vikingCharacter =
    (GameCharacter*)[[self parent]
                     getChildByTag:kVikingSpriteTagValue];
    CGRect vikingBoudingBox =
    [vikingCharacter adjustedBoundingBox];
    CharacterStates vikingState = [vikingCharacter characterState];
    if ((vikingState == kStateAttacking) && (CGRectIntersectsRect ([self adjustedBoundingBox], vikingBoudingBox))) {
        if (characterState != kStateTakingDamage) {
            [self changeState:kStateTakingDamage];
            return;
        }
    }
    if ((([self numberOfRunningActions] == 0) && (characterState != kStateDead)) ) {
        CCLOG(@"TBT Going to Idle");
        [self changeState:kStateIdle];
        return;
    }

}


-(void)initAnimations {  
    [self setTransmittingAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"transmittingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];

    [self setThrowingAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"throwingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];

    [self setAfterThrowingAnim:[self loadPlistForAnimationWithName:@"afterThrowingAnim" andClassName:NSStringFromClass([self class])]];
}

-(id) initWithSpriteFrameName:(NSString*)frameName{
    if ((self=[super init])) {
        if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:frameName])) {

            CCLOG(@"### TBT initialized");
            [self initAnimations];                                   
            characterHealth = 3.0f;                               
            gameObjectType = kEnemyType1BT;                    
            [self changeState:kStatespawning];                       
            }
    }
    return self;  
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are not adding the TBT object as a child to anything (i.e. CCScene/CCNode/CCSprite). Try adding it to "sceneSpriteBatchNode" like in the createObjectOfType: method.

```
[sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:tBT
                       z:ZValue
                       tag:k1BTTagValue];
```

Comment: Hi Skullz, Thank so much for giving a response. I thought i have already added TBT as a child within the createObjectOf Type into the layer. I have added  TBT *tBT = (TBT*)
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode getChildByTag:kEnemyType1BT];
into the changeState:(CharacterStates)newState method but this does nothing and when it is added it will no longer change the state to throwing at all and it just stays in the idle state. If you can give me any other ideas that would be great, thanks again